# How can I publish my paragraphs with Zeppelin 0.8.0?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

This questions it's maybe obvious, but I can't do it?
How can I publish my paragraphs in Zeppelin 0.8.0?

The docs says that you only need to copy the link that appear when you press "link this paragrah" and put it in your website page. 
I did that procedure buuuuuut. It is not working.

I did the simplest website page just for test it, just the `<iframe> URL </iframe>` and appear a whitebox without anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Test</title>
</head>

<body>
   <p>Below is an iframe.</p>
<iframe http://goku:8080/#/notebook/2DM1X52VT/paragraph/20180804-155205_969494590?asIframe width="800" height="450">

  <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
  </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't now if I need to config something else in Zeppelin because when I put another URL in `<iframe   URL> </iframe>` the website page works

Comment: I changed the config file _zeppelin-site.xml_  enabling <name>zeppelin.server.xframe.options</name> with Value **SAMEORIGIN** but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The way to solved it was installing in chrome a extentions Ignore X-Frame headers.